# Copying from notepad++ also copies the name of the file at a random location

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, cygwin

This one's weird:

(notepad++):

```
### Init mongo-express
docker run -d \
    --network mongo-network \
    --name mongo-express \
    -p 8081:8081 \
    -e ME_CONFIG_OPTIONS_EDITORTHEME="ambiance" \
    -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER="mongodb" \
    -e ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME="<user>" \
    -e ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD="<pass>" \
    -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL="mongodb://<user>:<pass>@mongodb:27017/" \
    --name mongo-express mongo-express
```

adding image for clarity:

[image]

Copying the above into a cygwin terminal produces:

```
 docker run -d \
>     --network mongo-network \
>     --name mongo-express \
>     -p 8081:8081 \
>     -e ME_CONFIG_OPTIONS_EDITORTHEME="ambiance" \
>     -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER="mongodb" \
>     -e ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME="<user>" \
>     -e ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD="<pass>" \
> notes.md -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL="mongodb://<user>:<pass>@mongodb:27017/" \
>     --name mongo-express mongo-express
```

The `notes.md` argument is the name of the file. How and why does it get pasted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running into the difference between line-endings
characters (new-line) between Windows and Linux.

Notepad++ by default uses the Windows line-end sequence, which is
"carriage-return linefeed". Linux only uses the linefeed.

To force Notepad++ to use the Linux line-end convention, use its menu
*Edit > EOL conversion > Unix (LF)*.
Now when you copy your text, it won't be mangled by cygwin.

Comment: But where does the file name come from?

Comment: The file name is not affected by this setting, but I'm not sure I understood your comment.

Comment: Wasn't clear; why is the file name pasted into cygwin? It's not actually anywhere in the file (the file does not contain the string "notes.md")

Comment: I can't duplicate this problem - my Notepad++ does not do that. You should test some more to find out if it's a Notepad++ problem or a cygwin problem. Have you perhaps dragged and dropped this file on the cygwin terminal?

Comment: No, just copy paste. Might be related to the cygwin version? 3.1.7(0.340/5/3), notepad++ v7.8.1